# Qt Qml - android - adjust listview scroll speed/velocity

Tags: android, qt, listview, qml

[Qt Quick 2.0 (qml) - Android]
I searched but I don't get how one can increase the velocity of the scrolling in a listview:

```
ListView {
    width: 180; height: 200

    Component {
        id: contactsDelegate
        Rectangle {
            id: wrapper
            width: 180
            height: yeah.height
            Column{
               id:yeah
               Text {
                   id: contactInfo
                   text: name + ": " + number
               }
               Image{
                   source: jpgsrc
               }
            }
        }
    }

    model: ContactModel {}
    delegate: contactsDelegate
    focus: true
}
```

#### Question

Say my ContactModel has 200 elements. My problem is that the scrolling speed over those elements is too slow. It takes too long to scroll the whole list.

I would like to know how to modify that code to make the scrolling experience faster (at least with a higher velocity).

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the docs? Have a look at `verticalVelocity` or `horizontalVelocity` which can be found here: `http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html`

Comment: @sk2212: +1 I missed the fact that Listview inherited from Flickable.. shame on me. Thanks sk2212

Comment: @Lary No one has to shame for not reading the docs ;-).

Comment: @sk2212 :) you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To improve speed of scrolling you can play with 2 `ListView` properties: `cacheBuffer` and `maximumFlickVelocity`.

`maximumFlickVelocity` directly impacts speed whereas `cacheBuffer` should be updated if you have speed issues due to slow dynamic loading of `ListView` elements.

Comment: Next time, I will be careful with the inheritance options :) Thanks