# Delayed scroll in QML ListView with draggable items

Tags: listview, scroll, qml, qt5, drag

Some time ago had implemented `ListView` with draggable items by the following tutorial: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-dynamicview-tutorial.html So ListView items delegate is a `MouseArea`.

Dragging works fine, however scrolling has some glitches on touchpads  (Linux or Android tablet): scrolling starts after 2-3 seconds fingers movements, not immediately. Very annoying! Tried different `ListView` or `Flickable` properties with no luck. Any solution or workaround exists?

Scrolling with mouse wheel or laptop touchpad works fine - immediate scrolling, with fingers - glitches. Is it a programming bug, performance issue or Qt problem/bug?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35538634/630169) given me some tips to alter `cacheBuffer` property which I made delayed previously to avoid binding loop:

```
    Binding on cacheBuffer {
        value: Math.max((listView.contentItem.height + listView.spacing) *
                        listView.count - listView.height, 0)
        delayed: true   // Prevent intermediary values from being assigned
    }
```

Removing delayed property and fixing binding loop made scrolling much more responsive and fast, however still have 2-3 sec delay before starting scrolling:

```
    cacheBuffer: count > 0 ? (contentItem.height + spacing) * count
                           : itemHeight
```

So I scroll once - no reaction. 2-3 sec passed, scroll 2nd time - works fine. Where to dig next? Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read some scroll performance tips:

- https://wiki.qt.io/Performance_tip_Lists
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html#views

and came to some conclusions.

### 1. Heavy bindings

And remove some bindings and properties which could degrade the performance. One of them was

```
property real contentHeight: listView.contentHeight
```

property in list item delegate and its `on..Change` signal handler. Made some optimizations in other handlers as well.

### 2. Fixed `cacheBuffer` property value in the `ListView`

Doing some tests come to conclusion with dynamic property it could lead to come cached items clean up with degrades performance an leads to some other unwanted side effects due to items clean up and disappearing. I.e.:

```
    cacheBuffer: 4096
```

### 3. Unnecessary property in draggable `MouseArea`

Compared my implementation of `MouseArea` (`dragArea`) structure and properties with [Qt example origin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-tutorials-dynamicview-dynamicview2-example.html) and discovered it does not have `propagateComposedEvents` property - removed it and voila - all works fine!!!

Seems this property has unwanted side effects on scrolling on touch screens with fingers, as list scrolled fine and immediatelly with mouse wheel or laptop touchpad.

### 4.Convert `ListView` to `Flickable`

To eliminate caching completely `ListView` could be also converted  to `Flickable` with `Repeater` inside `Column`.

```
  Flickable {
    Column {
        Repeater {
            model: myItems

            delegate: listItem { }
        }
     }
  }
```